# pandas merge giving more rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two panda dataframe that I need to join merge.

```
nd = cu.groupby('division')['usage'].nsmallest(5).rename('t_usage').reset_index()
nd = nd.merge(cu, left_on='level_1', right_index = True)
nd.shape
```

I have basically taken top 5 elements by usage in each division but when I merge this to my main dataframe I get lot of extra row. I am inner-joining on the level_1 which is the old index in the new dataframe over "right index".

expected row count: 92, actual row count after merge: 737.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: It seems some duplicates...

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: i am sorry i can't post data. But does the code look right? I could see new indices in the final dataframe though now sure how they would come in!

Comment: when in increase the nsmallest count to 2 or 20, output shape still stays same...

Comment: Hmmm, are dupes in `level_1` column?

Comment: no, there are no dupes in level_1

Comment: So `t_usage'` is duplicated... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159161/discussion-between-vivek-and-jezrael).

Comment: If you can't post your actual data, then post a [mcve], that's what you're supposed to do. We don't want to see your data - we won't do anything with it, but you can't expect us to help without giving us that minimum amount of information.

Comment: Respect your comments,  but my concern is on the formula,  if folks could see anything with their xp.  That being said I did generate a dummy data set...

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be simplify with `apply` and [`nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html):

```
np.random.seed(1997)

cu = pd.DataFrame({'division':np.random.choice(list('abcdef'), size=30),
                   'usage':np.random.randint(100, size=30),
                   'cols':np.random.randint(10, size=30)})

print (cu)
```

---

```
    cols division  usage
0      5        f      0
1      0        b     22
2      2        a     73
3      6        a     38
4      5        c     82
5      9        b     39
6      5        a      9
7      2        a     81
8      9        b     27
9      5        b     27
10     7        e     90
11     1        d     13
12     1        f     33
13     4        b     21
14     9        a     27
15     6        f     89
16     5        a     20
17     3        c     98
18     6        b     74
19     9        a     82
20     3        f     52
21     8        c     79
22     6        f     17
23     0        d     91
24     9        d     73
25     8        e     33
26     9        d      1
27     1        f     52
28     7        d     40
29     3        f     16
```

---

```
nd = cu.groupby('division', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(5, 'usage'))
print (nd)

    cols division  usage
6      5        a      9
16     5        a     20
14     9        a     27
3      6        a     38
2      2        a     73
13     4        b     21
1      0        b     22
8      9        b     27
9      5        b     27
5      9        b     39
21     8        c     79
4      5        c     82
17     3        c     98
26     9        d      1
11     1        d     13
28     7        d     40
24     9        d     73
23     0        d     91
25     8        e     33
10     7        e     90
0      5        f      0
29     3        f     16
22     6        f     17
12     1        f     33
20     3        f     52
```